# How to convert date to 'ccyymmddhhmmss' format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date-format

How to convert date to 'ccyymmddhhmmss' format in c#?

Comment: y=Year M=Month d=Day h=Hour m=Minutes s=Seconds. What do you mean by c?

Comment: @chris_techno25 My bet's on "century"

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Thank you Sir. I have never used c before. Is it really included in the formatting letters?

Comment: mm for The minute, from 00 through 59.MM for The month, from 01 through 12.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Hi all ,thank you very much for kind support...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to try this... I don't know if cc is included, so I solved for the cc.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
string format = "yyMMddhhmmss";
Console.WriteLine(((Convert.ToInt32(time.ToString("yyyy")) / 100) + 1).ToString() + time.ToString(format));
```

For "yyMMddhhmmss".....Try this...And don't forget that capital `M` is Month and lower case `m` is minutes.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("8 Oct 10 19:00");
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyMMddhhmmss"));
```

Comment: I added a +1 since we're in the 21st century now. It's always rounded up.

Comment: @Narasimha No problem :) Don't worry... It's a give and take situation. I might need your help one day. Let's all help each other :)

Comment: First of all, I could be wrong, but I don't think you can directly convert this into the format you want because this is not a valid date format. We need to reformat this into a valid date then we can format it the usual way. Hold on. I'll do test this with my Visual Studio if it's accepted or not.

Comment: Alright my bad... It is a valid date format... I edited the code above. Check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question, you want to format a c# date object to the specified format?

The easiest way to do that is by using the date.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") - where date is the Date Object... There are several choices to this - like having 12-hour instead of 24-hour etc. The best option is to read through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx and set what you need.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

@Chris_techno25: I took the freedom to extend your answer:

If we stick to the question of Narashima, he wants the format `ccyymmddhhmmss`.
So I've scratched up this extension method:

```
public static string IncludeCentury(this DateTime sourceDate, bool replace)
{
  var source = String.Format("{0}/{1}", sourceDate.Year / 100 + 1, sourceDate);
  if(replace)
    return Regex.Replace(source, "[^0-9]", "");
  else
    return source;
}
```

Usage:

```
var includingCentury = DateTime.Now.IncludeCentury(true)
var includingCentury = DateTime.Now.IncludeCentury(false)
```

Output:

```
21218201491410
21/2/18/2014 9:18:10 AM
```

Comment: neither `21218201491410` nor `21/2/18/2014 9:18:10 AM` are in `ccyymmddhhmmss` format, so what's the point of this answer?